# Restoring original state of member variables set by a method when coming out of it

Tags: java

I have a class, of which one of the members is a boolean flag.

```
class Node
{
    String name;
    boolean flag;
    public Node(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name = name;
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

I have created an array of these **Node**s

```
ArrayList<Node> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have a method called funhello which sets the flag of the first Node in this ArrayList to true.

```
public void funhello()
    {
        myArrayList.get(0).flag = true;
    }
```

I have another method called funworld which sets the flag of the second Node in this ArrayList to true.

```
public void funworld()
    {
        myArrayList.get(1).flag = true;
    }
```

However, assume that these are independent functions, and I want funworld() to see the myArrayList in the same state as it was prior to calling funhello(). How can I ensure that the changes made inside a method do not have an effect on the members of the class, after I've left the method (without explicitly running a for loop and setting them all to false, of course). Is there a way in Java to do this making use of the language?

Entire code below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class postsodontdisturbmembers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDataStructure myDataStructure = new MyDataStructure();

        myDataStructure.addMembers("A");
        myDataStructure.addMembers("B");
        myDataStructure.addMembers("C");
        myDataStructure.addMembers("D");
        myDataStructure.addMembers("E");

        System.out.println("calling funhello...");myDataStructure.funhello();myDataStructure.print();System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("calling funworld...");myDataStructure.funworld();myDataStructure.print();System.out.println("");
    }
}

class MyDataStructure
{
    ArrayList<Node> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addMembers(String name)
    {
        myArrayList.add(new Node(name));
    }

    public void setflag(String name)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<myArrayList.size();i++)
        {
            if(myArrayList.get(i).name.equals(name))
                myArrayList.get(i).flag = true;
        }
    }

    public void funhello()
    {
        myArrayList.get(0).flag = true;
    }

    public void funworld()
    {
        myArrayList.get(1).flag = true;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<myArrayList.size();i++)
            System.out.println(myArrayList.get(i).name + " : " + myArrayList.get(i).flag);
    }
}

class Node
{
    String name;
    boolean flag;
    public Node(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name = name;
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it about concurrency ?

Comment: Generally speaking, the approach is to use distinct objects for something like this. It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @chrylis, say I am implementing both BFS and DFS on a graph, and calling both of these methods one after the other. By the time BFS is completed, all nodes in the graph have been visited. So DFS would print empty. However, before starting DFS, I want all nodes to be set as unvisited. Is there a way in Java using some keyword (private/public etc) or design pattern to take care of this?

Comment: Each *operation* has state that's completely distinct from the state of *the graph* itself, and your issue is coming from mixing the two. You need to keep the "visited" state in its own data structure of some variety.

Comment: @chrylis, you mean inside the BFS method, have a local boolean array for storing visited? like boolean[] visited = new boolean[no. of vertices] ?

Comment: @saltandwater Or some data structure; not sure offhand what the best one would be. You'd create it in the caller for the root of the traversal and pass it on the stack down the recursive call, but it wouldn't be attached to the core data structure itself.